# GeoDjango: How to create a boundingbox from a central point with 10km x 10km size

Tags: python, django, point, geodjango, bounding-box

How can I create a boundingbox starting from a central point with a size of 10km x 10km?

Right now, I am doing it as below. But this is not a good and accurate solution.

```
lng30km = 0.42 # I measured this values with google maps
lat30km = 0.27 # It is not accurate and won't work properly 
minx = point.x - lng30km
miny = point.y - lat30km
maxx = point.x + lng30km
maxy = point.y + lat30km
poly = Polygon.from_bbox((minx, miny, maxx, maxy))
```

I want to use this boundingbox, to find points in my MySQL DB within this boundingbox

```
MyObject.objects.filter(point__within=poly
```

Answer (score 2):

To accurately calculate the bounding box for a given longitude-latitude, you will need to do a geodesic computation. This can be achieved with the pyproj library. Detailed docs for pyproj are [here](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html).

Install the library through pip in your terminal.

```
pip install pyproj
```

Given your latitude and longitude, the bounding box are the corners at north-east, south-east, south-west, and north-west. Each of these has a corresponding azimuth value in degrees: 45, 135, 225 and 315, respectively. Now using the pyproj value, you can do something like this:

```
from pyproj import Geod

g = Geod('clrk66') # Create a geodesic calculation object
distance = 10 * 1000  # in meters

# given latitude (lat), longitude (lon) values for the location
top_right_corner = g.fwd(lon, lat, 45, distance)
bottom_right_corner = g.fwd(lon, lat, 135, distance)
bottom_left_corner = g.fwd(lon, lat, 225, distance)
top_left_corner = g.fwd(lon, lat, 315, distance)
```

The bounds of the box can be obtained from these corners.

```
max_lon = top_right_corner[0]
max_lat = bottom_right_corner[1]
min_lon = bottom_left_corner[0]
min_lat = top_left_corner[1]
```

You can use this to then create the polygon for the bounding box.

```
bbox = (max_lon, max_lat, min_lon, min_lat)
geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)
```

Comment: Thx for sharing. Why did you choose clrk66 ellipsoid? My longs and lats are from google maps. So I have to use WGS84, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have calculated sw_lng, sw_lat, ne_lng, ne_lat

Try this (only tested with postgres) I am not so sure about MySql. You should use PostGIS anyway. MySql has to many limitations.

```
    xmin = float(sw_lng)
    ymin = float(sw_lat)
    xmax = float(ne_lng)
    ymax = float(ne_lat)
    bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

    values = use_class.objects.filter(active=True, source__coveredby=geom)
```

---

For example (pseudo-code not tested):

```
geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

dis = 30000 / 2

top_x, top_y, top_azi  = geod.fwd(center_longitude, center_latitude, 0, dis)
right_x, right_y, right_azi = geod.fwd(center_longitude, center_latitude, 90, dis)
bottom_x, bottom_y, bottom_azi = geod.fwd(center_longitude, center_latitude, 180, dis)
left_x, left_y, left_azi = geod.fwd(center_longitude, center_latitude, 270, dis)
```

This builds a cross spawning 30000 meter by moving center 0, 90, 180, 270 by distance. Build a box with this cross coords and we should have it

Comment: **Once you have calculated sw_lng, sw_lat, ne_lng, ne_lat**

This is my question. How to calculate it?

Comment: I might be accomplished by using the `pyproj.Geod.fwd` method and the distance object `D(km=30)` using the angles 0, 90, 180, 270